# Using server-side updateSelectizeInput in Rmarkdown Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm trying to use updateSelectizeInput server-side to load a large number of addresses into a selectizeInput box in an Rmarkdown formatted Shiny app. Everything is working, but when you select the filtered value, it seems to be reloading the NULL value. Here is a reproducible example. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

````
---
title: "car_example"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
df <- mtcars

output$uiaddress <- renderUI({
selectizeInput(
  'address', label = "Address", choices = NULL
)
  })

observeEvent(input$address, {updateSelectizeInput(session, 'address', 
choices = df$hp, server = TRUE)
})
```

## SelectizeInput

```{r echo=FALSE}
uiOutput("uiaddress")
```
````

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this by adding ignoreInit and once to the end of observeEvent

```
observeEvent(input$address, {updateSelectizeInput(session, 'address', 
choices = df$hp, server = TRUE)
}, ignoreInit = TRUE, once = TRUE)
```